# Move files based on partial file name from array

Tags: powershell

I am trying to move files based on a list of prefix from a text file to match a portion of the actual files which are dynamically generated.

Example of prefix in text file:

```
103 1stCity
25 2ndCity
302 3rdCity
```

There are no commas and each city is a new line in the text file (not CSV format).

Example of files to search:

```
103 1stCity 20170901 12387.txt
129 OtherCity 20170905 354568.txt
```

Here is what I have:

```
$file_list = Get-Content "P:\some\path\to\PrefixOfClientNames.txt"
$search_folder = "J:\FilesToSearch_SomeStayHere"
$destination_folder = "J:\SomeFilesGetMovedHere"

foreach ($file in $file_list) {
    $file_to_move = Get-ChildItem -Path $search_folder |
                    Where-Object { $_.Name -like $file }
    if ($file_to_move) {
        Move-Item $file_to_move $destination_folder -WhatIf
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other method

```
$file_list = Get-Content "C:\Temp\prefix.txt" | %{$_ + '*'}
$search_folder = "C:\Temp\searchfolder"
$destination_folder = "C:\Temp\searchfolder"

Get-ChildItem $search_folder -file -Recurse | %{

$name=$_.BaseName
$fullname=$_.FullName 

 if (($file_list | where { $name -like $_} | select -First 1).Count -gt 0)
 {
   Move-Item $fullname $destination_folder -WhatIf

 }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If all matching files should go to the same destination folder you'd build a regular expression from the prefix file and anchor it at the beginning of the string:

```
$prefixes = Get-Content 'P:\some\path\to\PrefixOfClientNames.txt' |
            ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }

$pattern = '^{0}' -f ($prefixes -join '|')
```

then use a pipeline for moving matching files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $search_folder | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -match $pattern
} | Move-Item -Destination $destination_folder -WhatIf
```

Comment: Ansgar - thank you - it's going to take me a little bit to dissect your code but looks like it should work.  I understand Esperento57 syntax a little easier below.